# How to loop through custom post out return assigned categories?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to loop through my custom post type and then get the custom taxonomy then output all categories assigned to each custom post..

When I var_dump() $taxonomies I'm getting the name of the taxonomy. When I var_dump $terms I'm getting an empty array..

Any help would be appreciated

```
  function create_custom_xml_sitemap($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before)
  {
      $post_type = get_post_type($post_ID);
      if ($post_type == 'expertise_posts') {
          $sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
          $sitemap .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

          $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'expertise_posts',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,

        );

          $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

          if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

          $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
          $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_type, $taxonomies);
          var_dump($terms);
 
          endwhile;
          endif;
      }
      $sitemap .= '</urlset>';

      $fp = fopen(ABSPATH . "test.xml", 'w');
      fwrite($fp, $sitemap);
      fclose($fp);
  }
add_action('post_updated', 'create_custom_xml_sitemap', 21, 3);
```

Comment: You are passing the post _type_ as first parameter for `wp_get_post_terms` - it needs to be the post _ID_.

Comment: `$post_id` in `wp_get_post_terms` defaults to `0` - so you are not telling the function which post to look in.

Comment: I've added the full function now.. I thought this would be grabbing the post_ID when post is updated? Is that wrong?

Comment: _“I thought this would be grabbing the post_ID when post is updated?”_ - of the one specific post. Your are looping over _all_ posts of that type there - so using the ID of the one actually updated post would not make sense to begin with in that place.

Comment: You are still passing the post type to `wp_get_post_terms`, you need to pass the _ID_ of the current post of the loop.